# How can I just remove SSL for a specific URL /page on .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl

I am trying to remove SSL for only one sprcific page /URL on my (WordPress)website.
I have searched a lot on google, and I realized that I can change .htaccess file to solve my problem.

I add this code to my .htaccess file. However, it's NOT working.
btw, /testssl is the page URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/testssl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/testssl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I think there must be something I did wrong. Please help.
If there is another method that is helpful, appreciate it!
Here is the screenshot of my .htaccess file after I added the code above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEeKb.png)

Comment: How did you configure HTTPS in the first way? What would be the benefit of skipping encryption for a single URL?

Comment: It is unclear for me what you are trying to do. "Removing SSL" makes no sense if the rest of the site is still HTTPS. The most you can do is to make sure that the specific URL is __also__ accessible by plain HTTP, i.e. in addition to HTTPS. But for this you would need to adjust redirects from HTTP to HTTPS you might have in your config, remove any HSTS you might have set (since it affects the whole site) and make sure that none of this is cached in the browser (clear everything). So it depends on various things outside the htaccess file.

Comment: @NicoHaase I used cpanel to add SSL for this website. I was asked by my boss to remove one page SSL, he need to add a booking system on this url. He said someone did this before

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. It makes no sense to add a booking system within Wordpress that explicitly needs SSL disabled

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I was asked to make one page from HTTPS to HTTP. My boss needs that HTTP page to put a booking system.

Comment: "I can change .htaccess file to solve my problem" - It's not just `.htaccess` you need to change (in fact, `.htaccess` might not be the solution at all if there is a "problem" with HTTPS on this one URL. ... But if there isn't a problem then why force HTTP?). You need to also configure WordPress so that any internal links that point to this URL are HTTP and not HTTPS.

Comment: "Here is the screenshot..." - you need to add your complete code as TEXT to your question. You've put the rules in the wrong place, so won't do _anything_. They need to go at the **top** and _not_ inside the WordPress code block (read and follow the WP code comment). No need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives.

Comment: @MrWhite I just move the code to the top of WordPress Code and delete `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteEngine` directives. It's working now. Thank you very much :)